# update panel not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous-postback

Am using the update panel in my website and try to create the AsyncPostBackTrigger for a listbox. But it show the below error.So i try to create this event in page_Init section. It didn't through any error message.But i try to click the last item in list box means it postback the control and  go to the first item.Please help me to fix this..

> A control with ID 'ddl_discount' could not be found for the trigger
>   in UpdatePanel 'update_pan'.

```
 protected void Page_Init()
        {
            AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
            trigger.EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged";
            trigger.ControlID = ddl_discount.UniqueID.ToString();
            update_pan.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        }
```

Comment: Is 'ddl_discount' in the update panel update_pan?

Comment: You don't need to add trigger if your _ddl_discount_ control is already in _update_pan_, it will update when SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: yes it's in update panel but its postpack every time

Answer (score 0):

Try to put script manager in page instead of master page.

No need for any trigger.
It works for me.